# Question regarding the limit of composite functions

Tags: analysis, limits

Consider two functions $f,g :\mathbb{R} \rightarrow \mathbb{R} $. Assume that \begin{equation} \lim_{x \rightarrow \infty} g(x) = \infty. \end{equation} Under which conditions do we have that \begin{equation} \lim_{y\rightarrow \infty} f(y)=  \lim_{x\rightarrow \infty} f(g(x)). \end{equation} Thanks for the help!

Comment: What is the definition of lim g->infinity?

Comment: It's clearly true if the limit on the left-hand side exists. But the limit on the right-hand side may exist even if the left one doesn't (if $g$ is discontinuous).

Comment: @user571438: I assume it just means $\lim_{y \to \infty} f(y)$, with a slightly unfortunate choice of symbol (since $g$ was already used to denote a function).

Comment: That's correct. I made the edit.